# Does repartition(1) maintains order all the time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I need to zip two rdds that may or may not have same partitions, hence looking for repartitioning methods. I need to maintain the order while zipping and I know repartition shuffles in general. But the below code shows repartiton(1) is not shuffling the rdd. Is it only this time or can we guarantee it everytime?

Is repartition(1) similar to .collect because both of them bring the rdd to a single node??

```
scala> var k = sc.parallelize((1 to 100),4)
k: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> k.repartition(2)
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at repartition at <console>:30

scala> res0.collect
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99)


scala> var l = sc.parallelize((1 to 100),4)
l: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[11] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> l.repartition(1)
res5: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[15] at repartition at <console>:30

scala> .collect
res6: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `repartition` to a lower value (and 1 is the lowest possible number of partitions) you are actually performing the job of the `coalesce` method.

The docstring (and implementation) of the `repartition` method will be clearer than any reply I could give:

```
/**
 * Return a new RDD that has exactly numPartitions partitions.
 *
 * Can increase or decrease the level of parallelism in this RDD. Internally, this uses
 * a shuffle to redistribute data.
 *
 * If you are decreasing the number of partitions in this RDD, consider using `coalesce`,
 * which can avoid performing a shuffle.
 */
def repartition(numPartitions: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T] = null): RDD[T] = withScope {
  coalesce(numPartitions, shuffle = true)
}
```

However, if you plan to `zip`, consider that zipping will shuffle anyway. If you *really* want to be in control of partitioning, you re-partition by hand (perhaps with a custom partitioner, if you have a `PairRDD`) and then use `zipPartitions` specifying that you want to preserve partitioning.

In most cases, however, you may just want to stick with `zip` default implementation, which follows:

```
/**
 * Zips this RDD with another one, returning key-value pairs with the first element in each RDD,
 * second element in each RDD, etc. Assumes that the two RDDs have the *same number of
 * partitions* and the *same number of elements in each partition* (e.g. one was made through
 * a map on the other).
 */
def zip[U: ClassTag](other: RDD[U]): RDD[(T, U)] = withScope {
  zipPartitions(other, preservesPartitioning = false) { (thisIter, otherIter) =>
    new Iterator[(T, U)] {
      def hasNext: Boolean = (thisIter.hasNext, otherIter.hasNext) match {
        case (true, true) => true
        case (false, false) => false
        case _ => throw new SparkException("Can only zip RDDs with " +
          "same number of elements in each partition")
      }
      def next(): (T, U) = (thisIter.next(), otherIter.next())
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `zip` already does exactly what you want.

Comment: my concern is not just the order of the partitions but the order of my rdd itself. say i use repartition(1) (or coalesce(1)), will the order of the elements be maintained?  In the code snippet I put in the question, the order is maintained for repartition(1), can we guarantee that this will be maintained always?

Comment: Can it be the case that you are under the impression that by _shuffling_ we mean it as in _shuffling an array_? In Spark/Hadoop lingo, _shuffling_ refers to a computation that requires data to move across the network. For example, applying a reduction to items by key will make all items with the same key to move to a certain partition, thus _shuffling_. In this context, _shuffling_ does not break sorting, it's the same term with a different meaning from the one applied in general to local collections.